# How to solve the differential equation of the form $x\ dx=y\ dy$?

Tags: differential-equations

I try so not working.

```
DSolve[x Dt[x] == y [x] Dt[y], y[x], x]
```

I need to solve $x\ dx = y\ dy$.

Comment: `DSolve[x Dt[x] == y[x] Dt[y[x]], y[x], x]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DSolve[x Dt[x] == y[x] Dt[y], y[x], x]
```

> DSolve::dvnoarg: The function y appears with no arguments.

The warning says that the function `y` in some place is without any arguments, i.e., `Dt[y]`. Thus you need to change `Dt[y]` to this `Dt[y[x]]`

```
DSolve[x Dt[x] == y[x] Dt[y[x]], y[x], x]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The MMM answer is the simplest but remember how in textbooks they show how to solve an exact differential equation :

```
Solve[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(a\), \(x\)]\(s \[DifferentialD]s\)\) == \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(y[a]\), \(y[x]\)]\(t \[DifferentialD]t\)\), y[x]]
```